# How Stop Loading CSS file Just in index (yii2)

Tags: css, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i want load site.css in all pages except index
how can ignore this css load in just actionIndex ?

i put site.css in Assest so load in all actions

Comment: how are you loading the `site.css` is it using the default  `AppAsset.php` file

Answer (score 1):

You could use a specific layout for index (or for all the view where you don't need  appAsset )
and in this layout load a different asset that don't involve the css you don't need

eg : in you     you could create in you asset directory a MyCLeanAppAsset.pho with you specific  asset

view/layout a  new layout for manage this situation eg: clean_main.php

```
    <?php
    use backend\assets\AppAsset;
    use common\widgets\Alert;
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
    use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
    use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;

    /* @var $this \yii\web\View */
    /* @var $content string */

    MyCleanAppAsset::register($this);  //    a invocation for a differente Asset 
    ?>
    <?php $this->beginPage() ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">

   ......
   ......
```

and in your controllerAction

```
   public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->layout('clean_main'); 
        return $this->render('index');
    }
```